# Ethical crossroad: dropping contradictory cases

Tags: survey, reliability, methodology

I am currently working on my thesis and so I adopted 2 scales to measure two concepts. Before launching the survey, I 'paraphrased' the scales items in a hope to not copy them verbatim (excuse my fear of plagiarism). Anyway, the paraphrasing itself MIGHT have changed the meaning a little bit, especially for the 2nd construct. I say might because I am using the scales in a new country/new industry for the first time so perhaps it's the context rather than the language (domain is business/marketing).

Anyway, after collecting the data (which was a very hard step due to the conditions here), let's say that around 25% to 30% of respondents (~40 from 186) had actually contradictory answers on two questions and the following reverse-coded one. For instance (using 7-pointed Likert scale):

Q23: 'My organization can guarantee my intention of not stopping working for it' => answer was: strongly agree (a score of 7)

Q24: 'In this organization, remaining employed under it is my desire'
=> answer was: strongly agree (a score of 7)

Above are desired but then:

Q26: 'I am resigning from my work in the near future'
=> answer was: strongly agree (a score of 7)

This has tremendously affected my Cronbach and sent it to around 0.62. It is pretty clear that we have a case of a contradictory answer. How should I deal with such cases? To test things, I removed all the 40 cases and my Cronbach increased to 0.77!

Is it ethical to remove such offending cases provided that **I clearly explain in my data collection section that I am going to exclude some cases for bla bla bla reasons?** Is this an acceptable academic practice? I surely cannot collect a whole new set of samples anymore so I really need to move on with my thesis but I want an acceptable solution (if I leave things as they are, it will be a mess of reliability/validity/factors). As far as I know, such a practice was advocated on ResearchGate for 1 particular question but I will try to support it from the literature.

Opinion? Thanks.

EDIT: After clearly thinking about it, Q24 and Q26 can coexist! However and if we take Q23 as it is, it cannot coexist with Q26 since if your organization can guarantee your continued service, you won't resign soon! (Assuming that you're telling the truth). However, if I remove Q24, the reliability won't increase since there are only three items left (with one of them being a question to leave on the long-term which is totally acceptable regardless of other questions).

HOW TO PROCEED: instead of dropping the respondents, I think I have two ways to proceed:

1. Either sum up the scores of the questions of each and every respondent and get one average to use
   it as one dependent variable (to use all the 4 questions of the
   respondents). This way, I can proceed with all data and skip validity/reliability issues. However, I am not sure if this is a valid step to do.
2. Or simply note that the 'intention
   to remain' is an observable (and not a latent) variable and go ahead
   based on Q25 ('My long-term plan poses an intention to be employed
   elsewhere') and on Q26 at the same time but use these variables on
   separate analysis where I can study my notion on the short term (due
   to Q26) and also on the long term (due to Q25). I think this turns
   my weakness into a strong point of view.
3. A third option would be simply go ahead with my thesis analysis
   since only around 25% of the sample have weak answers. Base my
   reliability on the composite reliability one (which will be above
   .70) since a combined construct of retention will give a better
   statistical power in the analysis. However, there will be a big difference betwen alpha and the composite reliability score (.62 vs .73 for instance). Can I carry on with this despite having a few items correlating at only 0.120? If I drop such items, we're back to the basic point of having only 2 or 1 item for the construct! (Note that factor loadings are all above 0.6 for all the 4 items)

Comment: Have you discussed the issue with your advisor and/or colleagues? I am not certain this forum is the place to get the answers you seek.

Comment: The phrasing of some of those items/questions is very confusing. Did you get anyone to check them before you used them?

Comment: IMHO, Q23 is *incredibly confusing*. I don't do psychology research, but I might try arguing it's simply a bad question and should be tossed? If Q24 and Q26 give contradictory results, maybe that's just the way things are? They seem like OK questions.

Comment: Not really but I will. But usually, what is the consensus on contradictory cases? @Glen_b,no sadly no, that's probably the mistake I made. I thought they are pretty clear and so I proceeded.

Comment: All your findings are limited by the quality of your items (your questions). That is exactly why it is common practice to test your questionnaire thoroughly before executing the experiment.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the scoring of the contradictory item?

Comment: I already reversed them prior to the calculation of Cronbach's alpha.

Comment: @R.AS. from the responses here, the issue seems to be as much or more about *reliable inference* than ethics. So you should be careful that any results do not depend sensitively on possibly unreliable interpretations of the responses. In my original comment, the intent was also "talk to people who would regularly review theses/papers in this area"  (e.g. your committee, peer reviewers for journals you would submit to). They will be best equipped to understand the appropriate standards.

Comment: My Dr. told me to drop respondents with contradictory answers on Q24 and Q26. However, even these questions 'can' be understood or misunderstood. I, obviously, can't collect new data anymore. Let's just say that I proceeded with Cronbach at 0.62 with all the 4 variables (despite having a composite reliability > 0.70), how much can I really trust my results? For your information, I tried to regress each dependent variable of these 4 independently, all led to similar significant results. Can I conclude here that my low reliability will just underestimate my significance? (If present, of course)